# Can highcharts-convert create multiple-page PDFs?

Tags: highcharts

And if so, how? That is, how can I create a PDF with multiple charts, and where each chart gets its own page? (Note the one chart per page requirement disqualifies http://www.highcharts.com/docs/frequently-asked-questions#export-multiple).

This is similar to [Highcharts: converting multiple charts at once using phantomjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178889/highcharts-converting-multiple-charts-at-once-using-phantomjs), which hasn't gotten answered that I could see. To reiterate: I strongly prefer an answer using [highcharts-convert.js](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/56-improved-image-export-with-phantomjs), not the export module. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What scripting language are you using for the backend? You'd basically want to convert the highcharts to pngs using phantomjs and then find a separate library to pull in the images and dump them into the pdf.

Comment: @Duniyadnd So are you saying that highcharts-convert can't do it?

Comment: Sure it can, all you need to do is either place the charts in one chart element, and then convert to pdf, or run the charts separately, convert to images and if you're using PHP, you can use libraries such as tcpdf to convert all the images into a single PDF document.

Comment: If the purpose of the multiple-page PDF is to allow multi-page printing, then you can do this by using Acrobat Reader, and print portrait. This will allowing tiling of the charts across multiple pages. Just need to set each chart size so that it works nicely with paper size.